# TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7

```
import json      

def get_dict_feature_name(terms):
    feature_name = {}
    feature_name['feature'] = terms
    return feature_name


def save_to_json(Data, json_filename):
    with open(json_filename, mode='w') as json_config:
        json.dump(Data, json_config)
        
#save feature name unigram, bigram and trigram as json file
save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_unigram),"tfidf_feature_name_unigram.json")
save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_bigram),"tfidf_feature_name_bigram.json")
save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_trigram),"tfidf_feature_name_trigram.json")
```

I'm using Scikit-Learn and want to try saving the feature names for unigram, bigram and trigram stored in the variables terms_unigram, terms_bigram and terms_trigram into a json file. However, an error appears.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [35], line 14
     11         json.dump(Data, json_config)
     13 # save feature name unigram, bigram and trigram as json file
---> 14 save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_unigram),"tfidf_feature_name_unigram.json")
     15 save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_bigram),"tfidf_feature_name_bigram.json")
     16 save_to_json(get_dict_feature_name(terms_trigram),"tfidf_feature_name_trigram.json")
##error##

TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

example data of a trigram column:
[1.0193326349590137, 1.0193326349590137, 1.019...]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `json.dump(Data, json_config)` to `json.dump(Data.tolist(), json_config)`

```
def save_to_json(Data, json_filename):
    with open(json_filename, mode='w') as json_config:
        json.dump(Data.tolist(), json_config)
```